# Apache server .htaccess set header for Content-Security-Policy causes 500 error

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I am trying to add 2 headers to the .htaccess file but when the site is reloaded it gives a 500 internal server error

First header is:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy: default-src https:
```

According to [this website](https://scotthelme.co.uk/content-security-policy-an-introduction/), this should allow any assets to load over https from any origin.

Second header is:

```
Permissions-Policy: geolocation=(self "https://example.com"), microphone=()
```

Obviously changing example.com to the proper domain, but [the same website](https://scotthelme.co.uk/goodbye-feature-policy-and-hello-permissions-policy/) says this should work but also causes internal server error.

Comment: Is mod_headers enabled?

Comment: A 500 error is the webservers way of saying "I have a major problem but I don't want to talk about it in public". Read the error logs of your server. They contain a clear message about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Header set Content-Security-Policy: default-src https:
> ```

[Syntax is wrong](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html).

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src https:"
```

Is correct syntax.

In addition you should verify that `mod_headers` is enabled.

Comment: Hey, mod_headers is enabled as i have a bunch of others. Thanks for the answer, that fixed it, i also added unsafe-inline. Do you know what may be the issue with permissions-policy? I actually tried Header set Permissions-Policy geolocation=(self "https://example.com"), microphone=() - i removed the colon after policy but still 500 error

Comment: If it fixed it, please accept the answer. Regarding your other line, read my answer again, and read the manual again. You're using the wrong syntax.